# Change settings for simple scan

Tags: settings, simplescan

we use 3 PC and 3 HP 6970 allinone connected via powerline.
To choose one HP 6970 as standard printer for a PC is easy and works well.
But simple scan don't use this standard device for scanning.

Is there a possibility to set one HP device as standard for scanning?

scanimage -L
device `hpaio:/net/officejet_pro_6970?ip=192.168.8.10&queue=false' is a Hewlett-Packard officejet_pro_6970 all-in-one

device `hpaio:/net/officejet_pro_6970?ip=192.168.8.20&queue=false' is a Hewlett-Packard officejet_pro_6970 all-in-one

device `hpaio:/net/officejet_pro_6970?ip=192.168.8.30&queue=false' is a Hewlett-Packard officejet_pro_6970 all-in-one

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think its going to be complicated but the only way I can see this happening is by setting an Operation Policy in CUPS which restricts operations to a specific IP address chosen from your 192.168.8.10/20/30 range. From your browser go to the CUPS page here: http://localhost:631/help/policies.html

Comment: this would also restrict printing to the choosen IP?

Comment: That's the theory. How it might work in practice will require some experimentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short Answer

To scan from your second scanner:

```
simple-scan hpaio:/net/officejet_pro_6970?ip=192.168.8.20
```

## Long Answer

From [Debian's SaneOverNetwork](https://wiki.debian.org/SaneOverNetwork#Scanning_with_a_Network_HP_all-in-one_.28aio.29-1):

> ### Scanning with a Network HP all-in-one (aio)-1
>
> To scan over the network from a scanner on an HP aio (one which is not
>   connected by USB to a computer) you need only to install libsane-hpaio
>   (without its recommended packages) and pass the URI of the scanner to
>   the frontend. A non-free plugin might be required for the scanning
>   function.
>
> The format of the URI is:
>
> ```
> hpaio:/net/<aio_model_name>?ip=<IP_address_of_the_aio>
> ```
>
> This URI can be given directly to the frontend. It can also be
>   provided automatically to the frontend if either a print queue with
>   the hp:/... backend is set up or mDNS broadcasts for the scanner are
>   done by the aio. Automatic discovery will happen via the print queue
>   if both it and mDNS are available as discovery methods.
>
> The IP address could be known from the way the aio's networking was
>   set up; or it could be got from the aio's front panel or deduced from
>   the output of
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/lpinfo -v
> ```
>
> Each printer model supported by the installed verion of libsane-hpaio
>   is listed in /usr/share/hplip/data/models/models.dat. Model names are
>   enclosed in square brackets; like so, [envy_4500_series].
>
> A frontend can be started with (for example):
>
> ```
> simple-scan <URI>
> ```
>
> Typing the URI each time can be avoided by exploring what your DE
>   (Desktop Environment) or WM (Window Manager) offers for customising a
>   command. For typing from a terminal you might find a simple alias
>   sufficient.

There are more options for setup as the link describes. The information on `alias` to save typing might be very helpful.